# Find all subgroups of S4 that arise as the image of group homomorphisms f: S3 to S4

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My attempt:

The subgroup that arises in S4 is im(f) for some group homomorphism f.
By the first isomorphism theorem, im(f) is isomorphic to S3/ker(f).
But ker(f) must be a normal subgroup of S3.
Normal subgroups of S3 are (), A3, and S3.

Therefore im(f) has three possibilities, up to isomorphism:

im(f) is isomorphic to S3/(), or simply S3.

im(f) is isomorphic to S3/A3, therefore isomorphic to Z2.

im(f) is ismorphic to S3/S3, therefore it is the trivial subgroup of S4.

Is what I have done so far correct? And if so, how do I go about finding all subgroups in S4 that are isomorphic to Z2, and S3.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: $S_4$ is small enough that you could write it out and then check which are isomorphic to $S_2$ (actually pretty easy to do). For $S_3$, consider what the quotient $S_4/S_3$ is, and proceed in a similar fashion.